# Blenderesse Freeze Generator Setup for Geometrynodes Fields doesn´t work on Text

Tags: geometry, text-object, geometry-nodes

i tried the Freeze Generator and it worked fine with my Objects, but it doesn´t work if i select a Text. I converted the Text into a Mesh and i also applied a Remesh Modifier, but it didn´t work. Can anyone say me, if i may forgot something? Many Thanks!

Comment: Hello ! Sorry but there are hundreds if not thousands of addons and plugins out there for Blender. Since it seems to be a paid add-on it might be really difficult for us to help you troubleshoot it. Have you tried contacting the maintainer through the place where you got it ?

Comment: Hello! Yes i´ve tried to contact the person, but unfortunately there´s no way for contacting him directly. I wanted to ask here in a more general way whether you have to pay attention to other points with a text before things like Geometry Nodes work normally on it or how the text is simply handled as a completely normal object. 

Comment: Have you tried Object > Apply > Visual geometry to mesh while the text is selected ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I´ve just tried it but unfortunately it still doesn't work. It´s really ridiculus. Everything works except the text..

Comment: Text objects are often generated with split edges.  Try running a Merge By Distance on all vertices.

Comment: Yes!! Thank you so much that worked!

Comment: I will make up some illustrations and post an answer later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text objects generated with certain settings will sometimes come out with split edges when you convert them to mesh.

[image]

Converts to all of these pieces of mesh or *mesh islands*

[image]

Selecting all vertices with <kbd>A</kbd> in *Edit Mode* and pressing <kbd>M</kbd> and selecting *Merge By Distance* will fuse all of the edges together since all of the generated vertices are on top of each other.

[image]